# Laravel - Route has a forward slash

Tags: laravel

here is the URL i want to access an articel in Laravel.

http://mysite.test/art-entertainment-articles/poetry-articles/guide-praising-comments-1.html

now article_slug is "/art-entertainment-articles/poetry-articles/guide-praising-comments-1.html".

i made a route like this.

```
Route::get('/{any:.*}', 'ArticlesController@article');
```

but it is showing error 404 not found. now i want to get article by matching slug like this.

```
$article = Article::where('article_slug', '=', $article_slug)->first();
```

what should i write in route? it breaks at slashes and count not read the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off using the fallback function like so

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```

This will catch all routes that are not defined above it.  Then you can add the logic to hit your controller and figure out the article you require from the url.